# K-NN algorithm with maximum distance to be considered a neighbor

Tags: machine-learning, k-nn, distance

Is there a variant of the k-NN algorithm where the label returned is:

- the average of values of the k nearest neighbors that are closer than a given threshold to the query data point?
- no value if there is no neighbors closer to the query data point than the threshold

The intuition behind k-NN is that similar points in feature space have similar labels. It seems reasonable to discard points farther to query data point than a specified threshold, above which you consider that two point's labels do not correlate.

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: not clear, are you looking for this on a supervised or unsupervised way? for regression or classification?

Comment: For supervised learning; but the question is independent of whether you want to perform classification or regression